# Activating a Theme Options page to Editor - not working

Tags: theme-options, editor

I used Ian Stewart's Simple WordPress Theme Options Page ([Source^](http://themeshaper.com/2010/06/03/sample-theme-options)) for my client's site, where I assigned my client as an Editor. But from the Editor account the **Theme Options** link is not visible.

I checked the `theme-options.php` for `add_theme_page()`, where it's used `'edit_theme_options'` as the menu's capability. But unfortunately it's not visible. I installed:

- User Role Editor, and
- White Label CMS

But in White Label CMS, I unchecked the hide menu thing. But the link becomes visible only if I check the User Role Editor's `manage_options` checkbox. But it opens the Settings menu to the Editor. I checked the `edit_theme_options` for Editor, but it doesn't work.

I changed the `theme-options.php`'s `add_theme_page()` capability to even lower to `edit_published_posts` (Author capability), but not worked here. I tried deactivating User Role Editor, but no luck.

Comment: Might want to rework that question? So far it's _too localized_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found the guilty one: it's **White Label CMS**.
[image: White Label CMS]

Activating only the **Site Options** did not working, when activated the **Menus** too, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be caused by the parent page of your Theme Options. As the function `add_theme_page()` is just a wrapper for

```
add_submenu_page( 'themes.php', $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
```

your options page is linked as a submenu of "Design" (using `themes.php`), which requires the capability `manage_options`. Even if the submenupage requires less, the parent is not shown for the Editor.

You could add your theme options as a different parent menu entry:

```
add_menu_page( __( 'Theme Options', 'sampletheme' ), __( 'Theme Options', 'sampletheme' ), 'publish_pages', 'theme_options', 'theme_options_do_page', $icon_url, $position );
```

Your editor should be able to see that in the menu.

The reference for the parameters in the Codex is [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page).

Comment: Thanks. Btw, I answered my question as I found the exact problem. But failing to save data as an Editor user role - showing `Cheati' eh!` :(

Comment: I changed the position of the page using the `add_menu_page()` as you suggested with the capabilities `publish_pages`. But the same problem - doesn't saving data as an Editor and showing error: `Cheatin’ uh?`

Comment: Oh I get it - you will have to allow the Editor to manage_options too, as your template calls the `options.php` to save the data.

Comment: I know that solved the problem, but as said here in [Trac Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14365): *"giving these users 'manage_options' capability is not a good idea as that allows them to do other things that they shouldn't be able to do"* Isn't it a WordPress bug? I wonder how ElegentThemes solved it (as said [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cheatin-uh#post-2902100)): *Elegant Themes has apparently fixed their themes in the latest versions. I verified their one-line fix described in [this thread](https://www.elegantthemes.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=165&t=123301).*